# Large amounts of memory allocated on setImage:

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, memory

I have a UIImageView that was created programmatically (`[[UIImageView alloc] init]`).  The app's memory stays in check until the `setImage:` method is called. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're setting your image to your image view using something like this:

```
[imgV setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImg.png"]]
```

The problem with using that is that the app ***caches*** these images. If you'd like to avoid caching images, use `imageWithContentsOfFile:`:

```
[imgV setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourImg.png" ofType:nil]]];
```

Also, be sure to set your image to `nil` when you're done using it:

```
[imgV setImage:nil];
```

I have had issues with this in the past, and here's some text from an email I got back from Apple in response to a TSI:

> There are quite a few cases where you’re using the API UIImage
>   +imageNamed: to load images but you should be aware that imageNamed caches its image data even after the returned UIImage object is
>   released. Replacing calls to imageNamed with -imageWithContentsOfFile:
>   as outlined below is a way to ensure full control over your app’s
>   image data in memory

Comment: I'm using [UIImage imageWithData:]

Comment: Are you setting your image view's `image` to `nil` when you're done with it? And how big are the images (pixel wise) that you're loading?

Comment: I have to wait a minute :|