# iOS - How to avoid memory leak when saving and loading images to display in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, memory-leaks

So this is more of a conceptual architecture question. I'm making a messaging app in iOS. Devices can send image messages. I am saving custom `Message` objects (which include images) to disk using `NSCoder` protocol. I want to remove the messages from memory when I don't need them (i.e. when the user logs out and disappears from users list view). I am appropriately encoding that user's messages to disk, and loading them when the user re-appears. However, on the messaging view (a dynamic `UITableView` where each cell displays the message content), the image content of the messages are cached within the `UIImageView` subview.

So, I am essentially creating duplicates of the images when I load the messages from disk. Every time a user logs out and then in (i.e. disappearing and then reappearing), the associated messages are saved and then loaded from disk (recreated objects), and my memory usage creeps upward once I go to the private message view and scroll all the way up in order to display all messages.

Ultimately, I want to clean the cache of message images so that I can free up memory when a user is no longer around. I have a good reason for saving messages locally; my question is: what is the best design for saving messages/images to disk, removing them from cache memory, then reloading them when I need to populate a dynamic `UITableView`?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559990/large-amounts-of-memory-allocated-on-setimage/25560033#25560033

Comment: @rebello95 This is interesting. I tried using the `imageWithContentsOfFile` in my table cell, but it didn't seem to help the memory leak. The table view cells never seem to deallocate. I can cycle through the cells and set the `ImageView` to `nil` when the view disappears, but this seems strange and didn't seem to work either.

Comment: when your view/controller is deallocated, it should release the memory taken up by the images in your table view

Comment: I've verified that the custom cells are not calling `dealloc`, but the view/controller is. The memory only creeps up when there are images in the table view and I push that controller and remove it again, so the leak has something to do with the table view cells. Is it possible that the reuse cells are somehow cached beyond control?

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice you to use some ready caching library like: [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), [FastImageCache](https://github.com/path/FastImageCache) or [Haneke](https://github.com/Haneke/Haneke). All of them are both using disc and memory cache, what will improve the speed of your tableView and decrease number of download requests.

You can of course make your custom solution, but it won't work as well as something written during months and tested via many developers. However if you want to, I'd suggest to take a look into one of these libraries and start by considering what they've done to make everything 'speedy'.

This way you just save URL in your `Message` instead of full image. These libraries will check URL, understand that they already have the image in memory cache and load it. You don't have to store it in your array of objects nor download again or save by yourself on disc.

Keeping your message objects on the disc seems weird, as this is slow - better to use database - CoreData/Mantle/FBDB etc, however that's your decision :) Also storing on the disc makes your `Messages` very easy to reverse engineering attacks and isn't safe.

Comment: These libraries are probably best for performance and I will likely consider using something like that in the future. For now I'd really like to use a more straightforward approach, and I really don't understand why the `TableView` cells are not letting the images go.

Comment: @SamS How do you call these cells? Do you dequeue them? Otherwise you're creating new instance each time. I think you're doing something wrong, because in messaging app you shouldn't see any memory problems in case it's written properly - the memory on iOS devices is sufficient. Have you investigated in instruments what's happening?

Comment: Yes i do dequeue them. I've verified that it is NOT creating new cells each time. I actually started getting the `dealloc` callback when the tableview disappeared, but only when I rack up a few dozen message cells. I noticed the memory increase when a user logs out and then back in, because the app saves the user's messages to disk, then attempts to read them into the cache when the user comes back. I'm not so concerned about the speed of reading the image files because by the time the user scrolls through the table, all the messages and images should be loaded into cache.

Comment: @SamS Cells are reusable, they should NOT be created each time because of performance. When you scroll, cell which disappeared is moved to place where you're scrolling. This way less alloc and dealloc happens, what is good for performance. You can set `yourImageView.image = nil` in `prepareForReuse` method of your `UITableViewCell` subclass.